# Copying file names

Tags: excel, vba, filesystemobject

I have the following code, but am looking to change it so the output only provides the first part of the file name. The file names are in the following format. `ZipCode_Name_Date`. I only want the part of the name which states the `Zipcode` to print out.

```
Option Explicit

Sub GetFileDetails()
    Dim objFSO As Scripting.FileSystemObject
    Dim objFolder As Scripting.Folder
    Dim objFile As Scripting.File
    Dim nextRow As Long

    Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder("")
    
    nextRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1
    
    For Each objFile In objFolder.Files
        Cells(nextRow, 1) = objFile.Name
        nextRow = nextRow + 1
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Please, replace `Cells(nextRow, 1) = objFile.Name` with `Cells(nextRow, 1) = Split(objFile.Name, "_")(0)`.

Comment: @Siddharth Rout Maybe, but too little to place an answer... :)

Comment: @Siddharth Rout OK. I will transform the comment in an answer... But, since the OP didn't send any feedback, I have some doubts that an answer will  move him better... :)

Answer (score 1):

Please, replace `Cells(nextRow, 1) = objFile.Name` with `Cells(nextRow, 1) = Split(objFile.Name, "_")(0)`.

Answer (score 0):

### Extract FileParts

If you write it as a function...

```vb
Option Explicit

Function GetFirstFileNamePart( _
    ByVal FolderPath As String, _
    ByVal FilePartsDelimiter As String) _
As Variant

    Dim fsoFolder As Object
    With CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
        If Not .FolderExists(FolderPath) Then Exit Function
        Set fsoFolder = .GetFolder(FolderPath)
    End With
    
    Dim fCount As Long: fCount = fsoFolder.Files.Count
    If fCount = 0 Then Exit Function
    
    Dim Data As Variant: ReDim Data(1 To fCount, 1 To 1)
    
    Dim fsoFile As Object
    Dim n As Long
    
    For Each fsoFile In fsoFolder.Files
        n = n + 1
        ' This is the place to modify what to return.
        ' 0 means the part before the first found delimiter.
        Data(n, 1) = Split(fsoFile.Name, FilePartsDelimiter)(0)
    Next fsoFile
    
    GetFirstFileNamePart = Data
    
End Function
```

... you can easily utilize it in the calling procedure (adjust the constants):

```vb
Sub GetFirstFileNamePartTEST()
    
    ' Constants
    Const FilePartsDelimiter As String = "_"
    Dim FolderPath As String
    FolderPath = Environ("OneDrive") & "\Documents\"
    Const dCol As String = "A"
    
    ' Using the function, write the data to a 2D one-based one-column array.
    Dim Data As Variant
    Data = GetFirstFileNamePart(FolderPath, FilePartsDelimiter)
    
    ' Validate.
    If IsEmpty(Data) Then
        MsgBox "No files found.", vbExclamation
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    ' Write the data to the range.
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ActiveSheet ' be more specific
    Dim dCell As Range
    Set dCell = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, dCol).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
    Dim drg As Range: Set drg = dCell.Resize(UBound(Data, 1), UBound(Data, 2))
    drg.Value = Data
        
    MsgBox "First filename parts copied.", vbInformation
        
End Sub
```